# Need help finding where Pset 7 houses check50 is finding errors

Tags: python, sql, cs50

Admittedly the code is quite ugly on this file but it still works and completed the assignment as outlined. The checker however is finding errors. I will include the link to that. My code is below. as ideas as to why they think the output is blank would be awesome!

From the checker:

```
"Expected Output:
[{'first': 'Luna', 'middle': None, 'last': 'Lovegood', 'house': 'Ravenclaw', 'birth': 1981}]
Actual Output:
[]"
```

https://submit.cs50.io/check50/10dd5ef79130cbd984475a9eaac72a8c3cf8f027

```
import sys
from sys import argv
from cs50 import SQL
import csv


# obtain file input
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Enter one CSV file")
    sys.exit(1)

# read file into reader
wizards = open(argv[1])
reader = csv.reader(wizards)

# create empty lists
fullnames = []
houses = []
yob = []
namecount = 0
# save name, houses and years from each row
for row in reader:
    if namecount > 0:
        fullnames.append(row[0])
        houses.append(row[1])
        yob.append(row[2])
    namecount += 1

# create empty lists
firstnames = []
middlenames = []
lastnames = []

# seperate names. couldve used .split() to do all this in hindsight
for x in range(namecount - 1):
    namelen = len(fullnames[x])
    tname = fullnames[x]
    spaces = 0
    # finds spaces in names using length
    for y in range(namelen - 1):
        if tname[y] == " ":
            spaces += 1

    nchars = 0
    # loops based on spaces and puts together names before and after spaces to save in respective name lists
    for s in range(spaces + 1):
        tempsn = tname[nchars]
        # adds chars to name until space, comma or end of full name reached
        while tname[nchars] != " " and tname != "," and nchars < namelen - 1:
            nchars += 1
            tempsn += tname[nchars]
        # saves temp names into lists
        if s == 0:
            firstnames.append(tempsn)
        elif s == 1 and spaces == 1:
            middlenames.append(None)
            lastnames.append(tempsn)
        elif s == 1 and spaces == 2:
            middlenames.append(tempsn)
        else:
            lastnames.append(tempsn)
        nchars += 1

# opens sql database
db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")
# for each name, puts associated data into table using SQL query
for h in range(namecount - 1):
    db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                firstnames[h], middlenames[h], lastnames[h], houses[h], yob[h])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's join to our loop already in progress. We're on the 'y' in "Harry":

```
while tname[nchars] != " " and tname != "," and nchars < namelen - 1:
        nchars += 1
        tempsn += tname[nchars]
```

It adds the space to `tempsn`.

You should listen to you "*# seperate names. couldve used .split() to do all this in hindsight*"

Comment: what a silly mistake on my part. Would've taken a while to find it. Also yes definitely when i saw that function afterwords i looked at my code like it was a heap of trash. You answered both the questions i have asked on this site and it has helped me a huge amount so id really like to thank you for taking the time to help me and others out as we begin this journey. I get to go back to my full time job as a pilot on Monday after layoff and your help has allowed me to get through the course with just a little less frustration so i can prep for flying again with ample time :)